# Is the new Gmail interface available for all domain accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

My domain is on Google since ~2006, the name changed a few times (Google Apps initially, now I think this is G Suite) and I benefit from the free grandfathering program.

I wanted to try the new 2018 Gmail interface but it did not show on my account in settings.

I found a [Google support post](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7684334?hl=en) which suggests that this new interface should be enabled on the domain console (in "*Enable Gmail for a domain or organizational unit*"):

> In User settings, scroll to New Gmail Early Adopter Program.

I do not have this *New Gmail Early Adopter Program* entry (there are three available: themes, delegation and name format).

**Will this new Gmail interface be made available to "old" G Suite domains?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered today that the new interface was made available to my G Suite domain.